# Magento: Mage_Core_Exception Invalid block type: Mage_Banners_Block_Banners

Tags: magento, nginx

Anyone any idea what is up with this Magento install?

Altered some settings on a vhost (unrelated to the vhost for this particular site), and afterwards this site stopped loading?

I changed the settings back but the page still loads incorrectly.

Here is a browser shot of what it looks like, as you can see, almost blank...
[image]

This is the log that Magento is throwing:

```
2014-07-20T14:11:41+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Banners_Block_Banners' in /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('banners/banners', Array)
#2 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(164): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('banners/banners', NULL, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->blockDirective(Array)
#4 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/lib/Varien/Filter/Template.php(134): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#5 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php(504): Varien_Filter_Template->filter('{{block type="b...')
#6 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Block.php(54): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter->filter('{{block type="b...')
#7 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Cms_Block_Block->_toHtml()
#8 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/design/frontend/default/fashionstore/template/page/3columns.phtml(62): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/nginx/dut...')
#10 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#11 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#15 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#16 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#17 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/index.php(87): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#22 {main}
```

Here is the nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name
        **HIDDEN**
        **HIDDEN**
    ;

    listen 80;

    return 301 https://**HIDDEN**$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name
        **HIDDEN**
        **HIDDEN**
    ;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate ssl/dutchbarnheadshop.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key ssl/dutchbarnheadshop.key;

    root /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public;
    #index index.html index.php;

    access_log /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/logs/access.log;
    error_log /home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ^~ /app/                       { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/                  { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                       { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml          { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                       { deny all; }

    location /var/export {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
        autoindex               on;
    }

    location /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }
        expires off;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $fastcgi_https;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   MAGE_RUN_CODE   default;
        fastcgi_param   MAGE_RUN_TYPE   store;
        fastcgi_param   MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE true;
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it's not loading! It's making me tear my hair out!

Comment: magento complies that, it looks for a block file in `app/code/core/Mage/Banners/Block/Banners.php` and couldn't find that there. So check that file exists there

Comment: It's missing, but I'm not entirely sure why? I just checked the zip file that the site originally came from and it's not there but it was working without it?

Comment: Not sure what exactly halppend. Now Magento requires that block to render the page content. So it looks for that block and couldn't find. Hence complains. So according to your Magento version, you need to find an exact copy of that file and then has to replace it there. **Note**: check that file in `community` and `local` codepools also (`app/code/<local>|<commuinty>`).

Comment: I had got the problem and it came from a deleted module folder in a commit without deleting the according xml. while the compilation was done and active, it worked but then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out the problem, after Magento started throwing an error on the page itself saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'this' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in 
/home/nginx/dutchbarnheadshop/public/app/design/frontend/default/fashionstore/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 52
```

So I opened up header.phtml, as indicated by the error and found this:

```
<?php echo $ this -> getChildHtml('qbanner.top') ?>
```

As you can see, the space between $ and this is unwanted, so I removed it, restarted php5-fpm and it worked again!

I think this is because this particular file was cached by php5-xcache and when I restarted the server yesterday the cache was obviously wiped. When it tried to reload this file, the file had a syntax error.

Thanks to everyone for their suggestions!